# asp.net mvc blogging engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, blogs

I am looking for some open source blogging engine build on ASP.NET MVC. Is there any production ready projects available?

*Note from svinto: I want this as well, but rather something that plugs in to any asp.net mvc site, using any DI/IoC or ORM. - Instead of creating a new similar question, I'm using  this one.*

These are the blogging engines I've found and their dependencies, subdependencies etcetera:

**[Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite)**

- [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

**[Atomsite](http://atomsite.net/)**

- [NLog](http://www.nlog-project.org/) (Logging framework)
- [Yahoo! UI Library: YUI Compressor for .net](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) (Minifies js and css, .net port of [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/))

  - Ecmascript.net modified
- [Tidy.net](http://tidynet.sourceforge.net/) (.net port of [HTML TIDY](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/))
- [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/Community/SgmlReader) (Converts SGML into XML)
- [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) (DI/IoC framework)
- [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx)

Both of these seems to be more separate applications rather than something you mix and match with other things. Does anyone know of anything that:

- Has a separate assembly (or one for controllers and one for models)
- Uses repository pattern
- Allows use of any DI/IoC
- Allows use of any ORM
- Comes with view templates that I can change

Answer (score 30):

http://www.funnelweblog.com - ASP.NET MVC 3.0, Razor, and used by a number of bloggers already.

Comment: One thing that turned me off about this is that it's "built by developers for developers." Something to keep in mind if you're looking for a WordPress alternative.

Comment: The big problem is that many blog engines online don't have walk through. We can install and use them but don't understand them at all.

Comment: To save anyone some time. I just checked this out. There is not a stable release. Upon build there are many missing namespaces...

Comment: this domain is not up anymore

Comment: The domain is down but the code is on GitHub at https://github.com/funnelweblog/FunnelWeb

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a [NBlog](https://github.com/ChrisFulstow/NBlog). Really lightweight. Best to integrate to the existing site.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you determine as production ready?

Oxite is in beta, but seeing as MVC is not yet at RTM, I doubt you'll find anything that isn't determined as a pre-release.

http://www.visitmix.com/Lab/Oxite

I hope that helps.

*edit: http://www.codeplex.com/oxite*

Comment: MVC is not in preview, the Beta has been out for some time and the Release Candidate was released earlier this week.

Answer (score 1):

this one looks good http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://orchardproject.net/  based on ASP.NET MVC 2, Razor etc

Comment: isn't this more of a CMS thing and not a blog engine?  also, mvc3 has razor not 2 if I'm not mistaken, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Worth to mention BlogEngine.Net in this posts, so:
http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

and here list of its features:
http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/page/features.aspx

and here the documentation:
http://blogengine.codeplex.com/documentation

**It's not MVC, but worth to consider it.**