# Closest blog engine to Wordpress in ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, asp.net-mvc-3

I haven't been very satisfied with all the blog engines I saw in asp.net, I just encountered one which seems better than the other and it's implemented in MVC3, I don't remember which one. Can someone remind me and/or point to me an asp.net blog engine that is closest to Wordpress as for its architecture plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of [Orchard CMS](http://orchard.codeplex.com)?  Also check out [NBlog](http://nblog.codeplex.com/) (disclaimer: mine) and  [FunnelWeb](http://www.funnelweblog.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much it was FunnelWeb :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably (appropriately enough) BlogEngine. http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

Comment: The one I saw is not this one, it's very recent that's why I don't remember its name.

Comment: It took a couple of seconds to Google up these links: http://blogenginenetmvc.codeplex.com/, http://nblog.codeplex.com/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491207/asp-net-mvc-blogging-engine, http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/ASPNETMVCBlogEngineContentManagementSystemOxite.aspx.

Comment: Thanks but the one I saw is not in the list, I remember it has its own website domain.