# ASP.NET MVC 3 embeddable blog engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, blogs

I have a website that I would like to embed a blog into.  I don't want a seperate website living in a subdirectory.

I already have OpenId Authentication and Facebook OAuth implemented and a lot of functionality in my web app but I don't have too much content.

I would like to add an easy way to author content using Windows Live writer but would like to maintain a consistent look/feel in my site.

Are there any blog engines in ASP.NET MVC that can be embedded or added as an MVC area?

Comment: There was a server control that added blogging functionality to an existing webforms page. It used to be available on code plex or maybe it was gotdotnet? Anyway i tried searching for it on codeplex and could not find it. Thats about the only thing i know of that could add dropin functionality. Have you considered adding a new folder to your site, setting that folder as a new application starting point and then uploading the blog app of your choice into that folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491207/asp-net-mvc-blogging-engine

Comment: Did you find one?  I think most people assume you're looking for a package that will do everything and not just one that you can embed into another application.  I'm looking for the same thing (already have an app built, just need to drive dynamic content in 1 section)

Comment: Nope didn't find anything.  I did however find an mvc xmlrpc nuget package and added LiveWriter support to role my own so all editing is in LiveWriter and I just store the html/slug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not look into implementing it yourself. [Racoon Blog](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog) has an implementation of what you would need to do to get integration with Windows Live Writer. If you didn't want to implement those features you could also just use Racoon Blog.

I would go the route of implementing it yourself. I've implemented pseudo content management systems on top of MVC and it takes about half a day to a day to get something very rich. Go for it.

What you'll need to do if you do implement it yourself.

- Reserved Routing for content pages / blog posts
- A windows live writer controller with appropriate endpoints
- Some sweat equity to get it how you need it

Answer (score 2):

Have to throw one out to the [Orchard Team](http://orchard.codeplex.com/).  Their latest release is MVC 3, a fast growing community and a really slick modular design.

Answer (score 2):

Hokey idea...but how about creating and maintaining your blog in a traditional way, but aggregating it to your site using RSS?

Otherwise, build your own blog engine, or build your site on top of an existing blog engine.

FWIW: I really really wish this desired functionality existed...direct blog integration into an existing site.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but I have heard some good things surrounding [Subtext](http://subtextproject.com/).

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what those good things are.

Answer (score 0):

There is one blog engine, that is [Oxite project](http://oxite.codeplex.com/), is an open source blog engine and its enhanced version [Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/) is also available